# Sails Body Parser Configuration

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js, sails-skipper

I have an application hosted on Heroku that sends **a huge** amount of JSON.  I originally was getting a bodyParser - request entity too large error (HTTP 400).  Googling around, I came across a few stackoverflow/github issue links

([Sails.js bodyParser - request entity too large on version 0.10.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460135/sails-js-bodyparser-request-entity-too-large-on-version-0-10-5))
(https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/issues/144)

in which I tried updating my http.js.  Now my body parser looks like this:

```
bodyParser: {
  fn: require('skipper'),
  options:{
    limit: '10mb'
  }
}
```

This resolved the 400 error, but now I am getting a Heroku H13 error:

```
2016-08-11T14:02:08.861774+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response"
```

At this point, I am kind of stumped.  I've looked at Heroku's documentation about an H13 error

(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13-connection-closed-without-response),

but I am not sure if

1. I need to configure more with Heroku (how I would even go about that) or
2. Do more with Sails bodyParser configuration or
3. A combination of the two

I am currently using version 0.11.2 of Sails.

**[Update]**

Researching more lead me to these links:

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2653

https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/issues/22

I noticed an individual had their bodyParser config outside the middleware block.  I tried moving mine outside as well, and it seems to fix the 400 and 503 H13 Heroku issue I was receiving (and I slowly tip toed away from the issue).  My new question is, why does the below work, especially since the bodyParser comment block is *inside* the middleware block?

```
module.exports.http = {
   /****************************************************************************
   *                                                                           *
   * Express middleware to use for every Sails request. To add custom          *
   * middleware to the mix, add a function to the middleware config object and *
   * add its key to the "order" array. The $custom key is reserved for         *
   * backwards-compatibility with Sails v0.9.x apps that use the               *
   * `customMiddleware` config option.                                         *
   *                                                                           *
   ****************************************************************************/

  middleware: {
    passportInit: require('passport').initialize(),
    passportSession: require('passport').session(),
    /***************************************************************************
     *                                                                          *
     * The order in which middleware should be run for HTTP request. (the Sails *
     * router is invoked by the "router" middleware below.)                     *
     *                                                                          *
     ***************************************************************************/

    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'passportInit',
      'passportSession',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],
    /****************************************************************************
     *                                                                           *
     * Example custom middleware; logs each request to the console.              *
     *                                                                           *
     ****************************************************************************/

    // myRequestLogger: function (req, res, next) {
    //     console.log("Requested :: ", req.method, req.url);
    //     return next();
    // }


    /***************************************************************************
     *                                                                          *
     * The body parser that will handle incoming multipart HTTP requests. By    *
     * default as of v0.10, Sails uses                                          *
     * [skipper](http://github.com/balderdashy/skipper). See                    *
     * http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html for other options.      *
     *                                                                          *
     ***************************************************************************/

    // bodyParser: require('skipper')

  },
  /***************************************************************************
   *                                                                          *
   * The number of seconds to cache flat files on disk being served by        *
   * Express static middleware (by default, these files are in `.tmp/public`) *
   *                                                                          *
   * The HTTP static cache is only active in a 'production' environment,      *
   * since that's the only time Express will cache flat-files.                *
   *                                                                          *
   ***************************************************************************/

  // cache: 31557600000

  bodyParser: function () {
    var opts = {limit:'10mb'};
    var fn;

    // Default to built-in bodyParser:
    fn = require('skipper');
    return fn(opts);

  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your middlewares inside and outside the middleware object. As the doc say, you put outside the middlewares that doesn't follow 'app.use(middleware)' convention.

Since your bodyparser middleware return `require('skipper')({limit:'10mb'})` and not `require('skipper')` which is very different, it doesn't follow the 'app.use(middleware)' convention and should be placed outside, at root of http module, as you did.

Comment: Lightbulb went off -- makes sense.  Thanks!